# If captcha is wrong, keeping the fields filled out (PHP or JavaScript?)

Tags: php, html, forms

I've made a form with quite a few fields. My old captcha outdated, so I had to use a new one (where I choose Google's reCaptcha). With the old captcha, then if people filled it out wrong, then they could click 'Back' or on this link (that I put on the handling-data.php-page):

```
<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">go back and try again</a>
```

... and then all their answers in the fields, would still be there. But after I've changed it to Google's reCaptcha, then if people forget to click the 'I'm not a robot'-tick-box and submit the form; - then if they go back, then all the fields are empty.

So how do I fix this?

I was thinking of passing the $_POST-array to a $_SESSION-variable. So if they click back, then the HTML-fields would look something along these lines:

```
<input type="text" name="foobar" placeholder="foobar" 
   value="<?php echo $_SESSION['foobar']; ?>" />
```

But is that really the way to do it? I can't be the first one to stumble across this. :-/

Comment: Why don't you add validation to that checkbox? So that people won't forget it.

Comment: @Akshay Google's reCaptcha is inserted/embedded as an iframe. I assume that you talk of a javascript-error, that pops up, if the checkbox isn't clicked, which is a good idea. I don't know if that's possible, since it's an iframe. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon processing the `$_POST` data:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["postvars"] = $_POST;
```

Then on the form page:

```
session_start();
<input type="text" 
    name="foobar" 
    placeholder="foobar" 
    value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION["postvars"]) ? $_POST["postvars"]["foobar"] : ""); ?>>
```

For dropdowns:

```
<select name="barfoo">
    <option value="foo" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION["postvars"]) ? ($_SESSION["postvars"]["barfoo"]=="foo" ? "selected" : "") : "" ); ?>
    <option value="bar" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION["postvars"]) ? ($_SESSION["postvars"]["barfoo"]=="bar" ? "selected" : "") : "" ); ?>
    <option value="example" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION["postvars"]) ? ($_SESSION["postvars"]["barfoo"]=="example" ? "selected" : "") : "" ); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice... How would you do the dropdown-fields then?